# How to ensure that detected anomolous values correspond with fraud/risk etc.?

Tags: machine-learning

If I apply an **unsupervised** learning anomaly detection algorithm to my dataset to detect observations that are fraudulent, how can I ensure that the detected class will correspond to fraud rather than another outcome? To my understanding, such algorithms (e.g., Isolation Forest) work by learning the joint probability distribution of the covariates/input variables, then flags observations that deviate greatly from the mean of this distribution. So how can I ensure that anomalies will correspond to what I want to detect?

My approach to this is to use PCA to obtain the vectors that maximize the variance of the input matrix, then only choose those principal components that have a high correlation to the covariates that are associated with fraud, so that observations that are detected as anomalous using these PCs will correspond to fraudulent observation.

How statistically sound is the above approach?

Comment: See my answer to the identical question https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/580837/6193